# How to populate/fill a dataframe column with cell values of another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, apply, lookup

I have two dataframes

[image]

[image]

dataframe 1 has around million rows.. and its has two columns named 'row' and 'columns' that has the index of row and column of another dataframe (i.e. dataframe 2)..

i want to extract the values from dataframe 2 with the indexes stated in the columns named 'row' and 'columns' for each row in dataframe1.

I used a simple **for loop** to get the solution but it is time consuming and takes around 9 minutes, is there any other way with functions in R to solve this problem?

> ```
> for(i in 1:nrow(datafram1)) {
>   dataframe1$value[i] = dataframe2[dataframe1$row[i],dataframe1$columns[i]]
> }
> ```

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
dataframe1$value <- dataframe2[as.matrix(dataframe1[c("row","columns")])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need a for loop to do this. Just add the new column to the Data Frame using the row and column names:

```
DataFrame1$value <- DataFrame2[DataFrame1$row, DataFrame1$column]
```

This should work a lot faster. If you wanted to try it a different way you could try adding the values to a new vector and then using `cbind` to join the vector to the Data Frame. The fact that you're trying to update the whole Data Frame during the loop is most likely what's slowing it down.

Answer (score 0):

Sionce your loop only consider the rows in df1, you can cut the surplus roes on df2 and then use `cbind`:

```
dataframe2 <- dataframe2[nrow(dataframe1),]
df3 <- cbind(dataframe1, dataframe2)
```

Comment: they don't have same rows